# Replication issue on basic 3-node Disque cluster

Tags: disque

I'm hitting a replication issue on a three-node Disque cluster, it seems weird because the use case is fairly typical so it's entirely possible I'm doing something wrong.

This is how to reproduce it locally:

```
# relevant disque info
disque_version:1.0-rc1
disque_git_sha1:0192ba7e
disque_git_dirty:0
disque_build_id:b02910aa5c47590a
```

Start 3 disque nodes in ports 9001, 9002 and 9003, and then have servers on port 9002 and 9003 meet with 9001.

```
127.0.0.1:9002> CLUSTER MEET 127.0.0.1 9001 #=> OK

127.0.0.1:9003> CLUSTER MEET 127.0.0.1 9001 #=> OK
```

The `HELLO` reports the same data for all three nodes, as expected.

```
127.0.0.1:9003> hello
1) (integer) 1
2) "e93cbbd17ad12369dd2066a55f9d4c51be9c93dd"
3) 1) "b61c63e8fd0c67544f895f5d045aa832ccb47e08"
   2) "127.0.0.1"
   3) "9001"
   4) "1"
4) 1) "b32eb6501e272a06d4c20a1459260ceba658b5cd"
   2) "127.0.0.1"
   3) "9002"
   4) "1"
5) 1) "e93cbbd17ad12369dd2066a55f9d4c51be9c93dd"
   2) "127.0.0.1"
   3) "9003"
   4) "1"
```

Enqueuing a job succeeds, but the job does not show on on either `QLEN` or `QPEEK` in the other nodes.

```
127.0.0.1:9001> addjob myqueue body 1 #=> D-b61c63e8-IFA29ufvL37FRVjVVWisbO/x-05a1
127.0.0.1:9001> qlen myqueue          #=> 1

127.0.0.1:9002> qlen myqueue          #=> 0
127.0.0.1:9002> qpeek myqueue 1       #=> (empty list or set)

127.0.0.1:9003> qlen myqueue          #=> 0
127.0.0.1:9003> qpeek myqueue 1       #=> (empty list or set)
```

When explicitly setting a replication value higher than the amount of nodes, disque fails with a `NOREPL` as one would expect, an explicit replication level of 2 succeeds, but the jobs are still nowhere to be seen in nodes 9002 and 9003. The same behavior happens regardless of the node in which I add the job.

My understanding is that replication happens synchronously when calling `ADDJOB` (unless explicitly using `ASYNC`), but it doesn't seem to be working properly, the test suite is passing in the `master` branch so I'm hitting a wall here and will have to dig into the source code, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The job is replicated, but it's enqueued only in one node. Try killing the first node to see the job enqueued in a different one.

Comment: Just tried, killing the `9001` node didn't enqueue the job anywhere else either :(

Comment: Still, maybe my problem is a different one then (the symptom is that processes fetching jobs remain blocked for long periods of time without receiving any jobs), I'll keep debugging and update if necessary.